# Media Player problems on click stop

Tags: java, android, eclipse, media-player

I've been struggling today to make make my button sound.
I wanted to make button to play sound when you click on it, and when you click **again to stop playing sound**
First part Is working, but then I added

```
if(mpButtonClick1.isPlaying())
{
    mpButtonClick1.stop();
}
else
{
    mpButtonClick1.start();
}
```

And since I added that part, when I click on button nothing happens. No sound.
Eclipse is not showing me any error. 
Here is my activity

```
package com.example.splashzor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Prvi extends Activity{

    MediaPlayer mpButtonClick1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prvi);

        final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.spalshm);

        mpButtonClick1.isPlaying();

        Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme);
        dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mpButtonClick1.start();
                {
                    if(mpButtonClick1.isPlaying())
                    {
                        mpButtonClick1.stop();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mpButtonClick1.start();
                    }

                }  
            }
        });     
     }
}
```

I would appreciate if you show me what I did wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the`mpButtonClick1.start();` call before your `if/else` block.

Otherwise whenever you click the button you always start it and then immediately stop it, resulting in no sound being played.

The logic should be:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mpButtonClick1.isPlaying()) {
        mpButtonClick1.pause();
    }
    else {
        mpButtonClick1.start();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: also change `stop()` to `pause()`. Calling `stop()` means it enters the stopped state and cannot be played again until you call `prepare()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: I wrote this but there is a problem. Once I click on any button, I can't play any sound again, MP is not starting. I have to restart application.

Comment: I edited my answer - you need to change the `stop()` call to `pause()`